# Is this correct setup for a simple cross ref table Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to django and not very good at building models yet. I wanted to see best way to setup a cross ref table for my project.

In my scenario I want to allow users to search parts based off either manufacturer part number or a resellers part number.

One specific manufacturer part number can be associated to many reseller part numbers but each reseller part number can only be associated to one manufacturer part number.

So for example Manuacturer A makes a widget and calls it w12345. Reseller A calls this widget aw12345, Reseller B calls it bw12345, and Reseller C calls it widgetxyz. If a user searches on anyone of those options they will be brought to the correct part which is w12345 will all its information like price, qty, picture, etc.

I set my models up below, is this the correct way to do this? Or do I need more models?

```
class Parts(models.Model):
    sup_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mfr_part = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sup_part = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    part_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    part_price = models.FloatField(max_length=6)
    part_qty = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    part_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None,     width_field=None, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    partxref = models.ForeignKey('PartXRef')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.sup_name

class PartXRef(models.Model):
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mfr_part_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sup_part_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.supplier
```

Comment: What are the "sup_part" and "mfr_part" fields in Parts, and how do they differ from "mfr_part_number" and "sup_part_number" in PartXRef?

Comment: sup_part is the reseller part number, and mfr_part is the manufacturer part number. They are the same in both tables. I guess I was thinking the partxref table would hold all the reseller part numbers that match to the mfr_part number and that would be used to dynamically fill the other table when someone searches for a given part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. The main issue is that the ForeignKey is the wrong way round: there are many possible PartXRefs for each Part, so the FK should live on the former pointing at the latter.

The other issue is that it is a fundamental principle of database design, called normalization, that you should never repeat data; there should be one canonical place where each piece of data lives. In this case, the manufacturer number should live only in Part, and the name of the supplier and the number they've assigned to it should live only in PartXRef.

Comment: Got it, this makes sense. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Daniel would it make more sense just to have one table with all the info? As I mentioned I am just trying to create a simple search portal for a user to search for a parts and see what reseller has them, so in the search box they can type in part of the description or sup part number or mfr number. The results then would should all the resellers who have that part.

Comment: No, you couldn't use one model because you have many possible sup numbers for each part. So you need a one-to-many relationship. But the query can just be `Part.objects.filter(Q(mfr_part=querystring) | Q(part_desc__contains=querystring) | partxref__sup_part_number=querystring))` where "querystring" is the query the user entered.